# Create a login form in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add two things to the Bootstrap navbar:

'Remember me' checkbox and forgotten password link.
I managed to do the checkbox but the link is not placed correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/wusMf/1/

```
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
</label>
<a class="help-block" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
```

I could fix it but I'd like to use Bootstrap features to do it, maybe using the checkbox CSS? I didn't see anything except padding and margin in that...

Thanks for your help

TL;DR
I need the link placed under the password field, like the checkbox!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your label and your link are getting block style.

To fix this:

(1) Wrap both your checkbox label and your link in a fieldset.

(2) For the link, change `class="help-block"` to `class="help-inline"`.

(3) For the label, add the class "inline (e.g., `class="checkbox inline"`.

Code:

```
<fieldset>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
    <a class="help-inline" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This works for me but I have 2 inputs and a button inline and I seem to have to put the fieldset after the button or the button is pushed below the checkbox. How can I fix this?